# How can I join together this querys sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot, coalesce

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://%20%20[1]:%20http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c7c2)

I have this table structure for Workers table:

```
    CREATE TABLE Workers
(
     [Name] varchar(250),
     [IdWorker] varchar(250),    
     [work] varchar(250)
);

INSERT INTO Workers ([Name],  [IdWorker],  [work])
values 
('Sam', '001', 'Director'),
('Julianne', '002', 'Recepcionist'),
('Jose', '003', 'Recepcionist');
```

What I want is to get for each job the name of workers separate by commas, like this:

```
Director   Recepcionist
-------    ------------
Sam         Julianne, Jose
```

I  tried to used this query:

```
 DECLARE @rec VARCHAR(MAX) 
 SELECT @rec = COALESCE(@rec + ', ', '') + Name from 
Workers where job = 'Recepcionist'  SELECT @dir AS Recepcionist
```

And I got this result:

```
Recepcionist
------------
Julianne, Jose
```

This works only for one job, but I need to add more, so I tried then to use this query:

```
SELECT  [Director] , [Recepcionist] 
FROM 
(SELECT [job],  [Name],RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [job] ORDER BY [job],[Name]) as rnk
 FROM Workers ) p
 PIVOT(
Min([Name])
FOR [job] IN
( [Director] , [Recepcionist] )
) AS pvt
```

And I get this result:

```
Director  Recepcionist
--------  ------------
Sam       Julianne
          Jose
```

I need to get the results in the same row separate by commas, how can I combine the two querys?
I accept suggestions, thanks.

Comment: `[Director]` doesn't seem to be in your DDL. Could you please edit your question to include the pertinent info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming in your example query you meant job to reference the work column. The following query should do the job as per your sql fiddle.

```
    SELECT  STUFF(
                    (
                        SELECT  ', ' + cast([Name] as varchar(max))
                        FROM    Workers
                        WHERE   [work] = 'Recepcionist'
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 2, ''
            ) AS Recepcionist
            ,STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT  ', ' + cast([Name] as varchar(max))
                    FROM    Workers
                    WHERE   [work] = 'Director'
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, '') AS Director;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, your code works correctly to me ;-D

Answer (score 1):

the way you would do this using PIVOT would be like this.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    (SELECT [work],
                STUFF((SELECT   ', ' + [Name]
                        FROM    Workers s
                        WHERE   s.WORK = w.WORK
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                        1, 2, '') AS [workers]              
         FROM   Workers w) t
PIVOT (
    MAX([workers])
    FOR [work] IN ([Director], [Recepcionist])
) p
```

another alternative to PIVOT is MAX(CASE)

```
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN [work] = 'Director' THEN [workers] END) AS [Director], 
        MAX(CASE WHEN [work] = 'Recepcionist' THEN [workers] END) AS [Recepcionist]
FROM    (SELECT [work],
                STUFF((SELECT   ', ' + [Name]
                        FROM    Workers s
                        WHERE   s.WORK = w.WORK
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                        1, 2, '') AS [workers]              
         FROM   Workers w) t
```

both of these allow you to separate the data by other fields like Company or Department

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
SELECT
    t1.job
        ,STUFF(
                   (SELECT
                        ', ' + t2.Name
                        FROM Workers t2
                        WHERE t1.job =t2.job 
                        ORDER BY t2.Name
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.','varchar(max)')
                   ,1,2, ''
              ) AS ChildValues
    FROM Workers t1
    GROUP BY t1.job
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but with your code I don´t get the result I need. With your query I get the jobs in rows and I want to get it in columns.